# MySQL First row id before and after that is greater than current row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hello I am looking to add a column called MMV that will identify the first row before and after the current row I’d that is greater than the value. If there is no applicable row use max and mins of table size. The result will be the MINIMUM of the two calculations.

The picture below shows orders 19 - 31 but notes based on table having a table of 50 entries. Just a quick example on excel.

Hopefully somebody can help.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use correlated subqueries.

Either with two of them and then taking the lesser value with `LEAST`:

```
select 
  idorder, 
  ordervalue,
  least(
    idorder -
    (
      select count(*)
      from mytable m1
      where m1.ordervalue > m.ordervalue
        and m1.idorder < m.idorder
    ),
    (
      select count(*)
      from mytable m1
      where m1.ordervalue > m.ordervalue
        and m1.idorder > m.idorder
    ) -
    idorder
  ) as mmv
from mytable m;
```

Or in one subquery with conditional aggregation (i.e. counting / adding up based on conditions):

```
select 
  idorder, 
  ordervalue,
  (
    select least(m.idorder - sum(m1.idorder < m.idorder), 
                 sum(m1.idorder > m.idorder) - m.idorder)
    from mytable m1
    where m1.ordervalue > m.ordervalue
  ) as mmv
from mytable m;
```

This second query makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0.